# Process tree CPU history usage, process tree memory usage (aggregated) on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, memory, cpu, process, cpu-usage

This question is general for Windows OS, but I would like to see a software for Windows 8.1, since this is what I use.

I'm looking for software, that will take a process tree (e.g. Chrome.exe processes) and will aggregate their CPU usage and track the history of this aggregate (process explorer does not do this).

I would also like to see a tree memory usage. (aggregated memory usage for a process tree - e.g. all chrome processes).

I would like to see all the processes (with ability to expand the trees or collapse them back) with the CPU history associated.

Process explorer would be a best place for it, but the CPU history usage is bugged (does not show - there is a discussion about this here (probably dead): http://forum.sysinternals.com/cpu-history-graphs-are-all-0_topic25930.html ) and the other mentioned functionality is not present.

Is there anything else that would show these information?

Comment: Probaby useful to mention your Windows (and Windows version) in the question header, explanation and tag).